# What is the meaning of "open" in "he swings the plastic strip open"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, verbs

I've been reading a text from the book *1100 words you need to know*.

Week 6 Day 1. The text is about an invention - an umbrella substitute. In this text, there is a passage where the word "open" is used but I don't understand its meaning. Is it a noun? Is it a verb? Or is it an idiom?

> When a person is caught in a sudden rainstorm, he swings the plastic strip **open** in a shape of a cross

The person already "swings" and what "open" is doing here?

[Online source](https://learningenglishbykai.blogspot.com/2009/12/week-6-day-1.html) (The original book says the same)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The word "open" here is NOT a *verb*. "To **swing** something open" is a verb phrase. In your case. it means *he* swings *the plastic strip* in a way that it makes *the plastic strip* open. **To swing** is the main verb, and **open** is the state *the plastic strip* is in after the action of *swinging* it.

Comment: Yes, just like you can kick a door open or I guess kick it closed.

Comment: So, `open` is an adjective in that phrase.

Comment: Yes. You can think of it as the state the object is in after the action (the verb).

Comment: I would say that in this usage, "to swing [something] open" is a _phrasal verb_: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrasal_verb

Comment: Thank you, Glenn. I know what a phrasal verb is. Actually, I've got a book on Phrasal Verbs https://i.postimg.cc/BnhDK1t1/IMG-8976.jpg The problem is that I didn't find it on this book. Then googled but still was not sure about it. That's why I opened this thread

Answer (score -2):

The word "open" should be "**into the open position**". Similarly, we'd return an umbrella **to the closed position** when the rain stops.

I'd say this is mostly an idiomatic usage.

Comment: It certainly means “into the open position”.  But this usage is completely standard, so I don’t think it’s right to suggest that it “should be” anything other than what it is.

Comment: So, basically, it means "to make sth open", right?